# Resampling and replacement while sequentially adding levels of a factor

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to run a function while sequentially adding sites (x+i) to a dataframe, which would result in the statistic plus the confidence intervals. For example, if I want to run a linear model with which I sequentially add a site to every iteration to better understand how the additional data from every site influences the fit. However, I want to include every possible site in each iteration to obtain the confidence interval for each iteration. In its current form, I am able to randomly sample a site, but not all possible sites for a given "x + i" iteration.

I know this particular issue could be addressed with the 'dredge' function. However, ideally I would set this up in a way so that I could easily [with some adjustment] replace the current linear model function with any other function (e.g., metaMDS, diversity).

I am sure there is a better way to perform this, but I am a relative newbie to these types of analyses. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have been considering passing the below function through 'boot' although I haven't quite been able to get this loop to function in boot.

```
# data
set.seed(45)
dat <- data.frame(site=rep(LETTERS[1:6],3),mean=sample(1:20,18),rich=sample(5:32,18))

model<-lm(mean~rich,dat) # the full model
summary(model) 


my_vec <- character()            # Create empty character vector
my_site <- character()            # Create empty character vector

for(i in seq(from=1, to=6, by=1)){ # increase number of sites at each iteration
  
dat_seq<-dat %>% subset(site %in% sample(levels(as.factor(site)), i)) # subset data based on number of sites
  
  model<-lm(mean~rich,dat_seq)
  result<-summary(model)$r.squared
  
  my_out<-result
  my_vec<-c(my_vec,my_out)
  my_site<-c(my_site,i)
  
  lm_results<-data.frame(sync=my_vec, site_no = my_site)
  
}
```

Comment: What do you want to output to look like?  It seems to me the only way to present this for every possible new site at every iteration would be to present the fit statistics for every possible combination of sites being present.

Comment: Presenting the fit statistics for every combination of sites would be fine. Although I was considering performing this with the 'boot' function, which would produce an estimate, bias, and standard error, after which I could calculate the confidence interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help?  Here I generate every combination of sites in the dataset (the `combs` list) then I `lapply` the model to the subset of the data corresponding to each element.  The upper and lower CI and R^2 are returned.

```
x <- unique(dat$site)
combs <- do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(x), combn, x = x, simplify = FALSE))

do.call(rbind, lapply( combs , function(x) {
  dat2 = dat[dat$site %in% x,]
  mod = lm(mean~rich, dat2)
  data.frame(sites=paste(x, collapse=""),
             lci=confint(mod)["rich",1],
             uci=confint(mod)["rich",2], 
             r2=summary(mod)$r.squared)
  })
  )


    sites        lci          uci           r2
1       A -8.3174474  7.221600752 0.4453499992
2       B -5.5723683  5.818599482 0.0701472479
3       C -1.8397082  1.928749330 0.0826810176
4       D -3.5504781  2.253774792 0.8895987733
5       E -1.9782218  0.783889792 0.9679338880
6       F -0.3642690  0.202676480 0.9291569087
7      AB -1.0726850  0.631838143 0.1141900799
8      AC -1.0156746  0.486238667 0.1932050717
9      AD -1.3744991  0.089962986 0.5972134174
10     AE -1.3425429  0.359346030 0.3914262598
11     AF -1.2542336  1.094735972 0.0088070439
12     BC -0.3148719  0.536493520 0.1155061842
13     BD -0.8115027  0.263460008 0.3337377806
14     BE -1.0264258  0.376744253 0.2923566879
15     BF -1.1047222  0.961865064 0.0091250127
16     CD -0.9745928  0.341039802 0.3088694252
17     CE -0.9413738  0.549038074 0.1178103209
18     CF -0.8967742  1.165648399 0.0317149663
19     DE -0.8081655 -0.063530819 0.7253472880
20     DF -0.4928491  0.673804531 0.0443092831
21     EF -0.9565739  0.524655918 0.1407909531
22    ABC -0.5962015  0.353999681 0.0493374108
23    ABD -0.8365224  0.110852413 0.3191087122
24    ABE -0.8760695  0.210841908 0.2303024575
25    ABF -0.8266745  0.633602031 0.0137712837
26    ACD -0.9065180  0.066518021 0.3731538462
27    ACE -0.8472338  0.235549937 0.2031338155
28    ACF -0.7522162  0.720252734 0.0003762516
29    ADE -0.9661169 -0.041025998 0.4863258317
30    ADF -0.7657306  0.559208857 0.0190378530
31    AEF -0.8971295  0.489083497 0.0647322193
32    BCD -0.5771897  0.206912590 0.1511964736
33    BCE -0.5802808  0.341276672 0.0509875519
34    BCF -0.5806002  0.737926299 0.0112444750
35    BDE -0.6864459  0.004527069 0.4375645756
36    BDF -0.5930715  0.460544893 0.0124799554
37    BEF -0.8077064  0.411788016 0.0776553121
38    CDE -0.7399438  0.108174895 0.3071099077
39    CDF -0.5535068  0.623295610 0.0028013813
40    CEF -0.6905084  0.598692027 0.0040352416
41    DEF -0.5691343  0.342877359 0.0468583354
42   ABCD -0.6438371  0.095450002 0.2145588181
43   ABCE -0.6248798  0.195737009 0.1195408994
44   ABCF -0.5714679  0.519529413 0.0011238991
45   ABDE -0.7459710 -0.015192501 0.3500598278
46   ABDF -0.6397934  0.354865639 0.0391438801
47   ABEF -0.7297368  0.343203399 0.0605325928
48   ACDE -0.7739688  0.003126375 0.3281841191
49   ACDF -0.6236834  0.433241141 0.0158627591
50   ACEF -0.6696598  0.429949692 0.0230490498
51   ADEF -0.6839477  0.287476657 0.0763805047
52   BCDE -0.5735044  0.083072486 0.2169111169
53   BCDF -0.4853537  0.426339044 0.0020758928
54   BCEF -0.5621108  0.444630022 0.0067151679
55   BDEF -0.5715836  0.240391871 0.0762941714
56   CDEF -0.5364817  0.363030081 0.0181252387
57  ABCDE -0.6208064  0.020647714 0.2391257190
58  ABCDF -0.5292293  0.315066335 0.0225784375
59  ABCEF -0.5621816  0.333684980 0.0228222717
60  ABDEF -0.6093804  0.195345360 0.0867885013
61  ACDEF -0.5890752  0.262323665 0.0502230537
62  BCDEF -0.4898635  0.265972273 0.0305394982
63 ABCDEF -0.5239122  0.198342387 0.0539903463
```